# php session_regenerate_id returns same id after session id regeneration

Tags: php, session

I have following php code to regenerate my session id. but its actually returning same value every time i load the page.

```
ini_set(session.save_path, "/home/web/session"); 
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 14400);
session_start();
    echo "session id". session_id()."<br>"; 
session_regenerate_id(true);   // change session ID for the current session an invalidate old session ID 
echo "session id". session_id()."<br>";
```

returns

```
session ddsfdfdfdfs9d72dc0832b0
session ddsfdfdfdfs9d72dc0832b0
```

could you please let me know why regenerate id is not working ?

Comment: Impossible that this can be the output. You echo session id . session_id() and not session. It has to be something like session idddsfdfdfdfs9d72dc0832b0

Comment: And you have a comment in your echo lol?

Comment: You should post the actual code you are using.

Comment: @Xatenev: its a formatting issue with my question in stack.i corrected it

Comment: @jeroen : I have posted original code

Comment: session idlq4ch50b1f96ohb5bnn04qukn2
session idnp85jr5jqkp6pok4fan609i6t6

Comment: @logan It certainly doesn't seem so as there is no `id` at the start of the output. And as it is, the code works: http://codepad.viper-7.com/BMgwDk

Comment: i have this setting as well `ini_set('session.cookie_secure', FALSE);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', TRUE);`

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting? Maybe the session ID could not be changed for some reason, e. g., as the HTTP header has already be sent and thus setting the cookie is no longer possible. You could also store the session ID in a variable instead.

Comment: So you have session.use_tran_sid enabled? If so, it should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

When running this code on my server, it successfully changes the session_id() every time. I did make SMALL adjustments that might fix your problem.

```
echo "session id". session_id().""; 
session_regenerate_id(true);
// change session ID for the current session an invalidate old session ID echo "session id". session_id()."
echo "<br>session id".session_id()."";
```

Comment: there is no change from my question. pls see my formatted question

Comment: Is there any way that you can put this all into one page on your website and give us a link to it?